# Timesheet Analysis eroor when adding custom new field

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8

I've added new field in Odoo TimeSheet Analysis.

[image]

The problem is, when i click on activité,i get the following error:

[image]

Here is how i inherit the `hr.timesheet.report`

```
class hr_timesheet_sheet_list_activity_report(models.Model):
_inherit = 'hr.timesheet.report'
lst_activity_id = fields.Many2one('timesheet_list_activity.activity',string='Activité',readonly=True)
```

If someone can help me , or give me a link where i can find a tutorial about modifying the TimeSheet Analysis report in Odoo.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The `hr.timesheet.report` model is creating a database view, which will handle its data. This creation is done by the `init()` of the model. So it is not enough to just add a field. The database view has to be extended also.

Comment: Indeed. needed to add my column in the select and group by instruction. Thank you.